# Problem with my code. I want to change the color of my pivot graph

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and this code that I am trying to do keep saying "Object doesn't support this property or method". I am wondering what is wrong with it or what to do?

What I am trying to do is that I created a button to change this data and every time the data change, so does the graph. But I also want to also change the color of the graph. But I do not want to select the graph at the end.

```
Sub Add_Value_Field()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim sField As String

'Set Variable
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
sField = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Text

'Remove Existing Fields
For Each pf In pt.DataFields
If pf.Name <> "Values" Then
    pf.Orientation = xlHidden
End If
Next pf

'Add fields that button was clicked for
pt.PivotFields(sField).Orientation = xlDataField

Call unselect

End Sub


Sub Unselect()

   With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill
           .Visible = msoTrue
           .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
           .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
           .ForeColor.Brightest = 0
           .Transparency = 0
           .Solid
    End With
End Sub
```

I want the code to run smoothly and not so glitchy.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A `ChartObject` is just a "container" for a Chart object, so you can change this:

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill
```

to:

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. That was just what I was missing.